# vba do while loop wont exit loop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I've been trying to figure out how to get this to break out of the do while loop.  The idea was to copy the first cell that found what I was looking for and paste it in a1 to use that as a reference to break the loop...but it is not working.

```
    Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="pdl", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Dim x As String
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate

    Do While True
        ActiveCell.Select
        If ActiveCell.Address = Range("a1") Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

It just keeps looping through the exit do.

Comment: All of the Activate and .Select makes this hard to read but try `If ActiveCell.Address = Range("a1").Address Then`.

Comment: It is not clear to me about your copy and paste operation. If you continually paste the found cells into new cells below where you have found them them the pasted cells are going to show up in the next find. This could lead to another continuous loop until you literally run out of rows on the worksheet. Please specify where you are finding the **pdl** values and where you are pasting them to.

Comment: Your comments say "and paste it in a1", but you never select A1 to paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
    If ActiveCell.Address = Range("a1") Then
        Exit Do
    Else
```

Activecell.Address will never = Range("a1") (Well it could but you would need the text in cell A1 to read "$A$1"

If you want to test if the Activecell is cell A1 then you can do this:

```
    If ActiveCell.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Exit Do
    Else
```

Or this

```
    If ActiveCell.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
        Exit Do
    Else
```

I would however encourage you to do some research on how to build macros without using select and selection as its very time costly to use them at run time.